# save row number in core data and order by desc

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, core-data, nstableview

I am working with swift 4 for macOS and I get my data from core data into a NSTableview.

Now I would like to save the order of my data.
Example:

```
MyCoreData1 (Row 1)
MyCoreData2 (Row 2)
MyCoreData3 (Row 3)
MyCoreData4 (Row 4)
```

Now I sort it with drag and drop like this:

```
MyCoreData1 (Row 3)
MyCoreData2 (Row 2)
MyCoreData3 (Row 1)
MyCoreData4 (Row 4)
```

How can I save this new order into core data?
At the moment I have an attribute "sortNumber" in my entity

```
MyCoreData1 (sortNumber 10)
MyCoreData2 (sortNumber 20)
MyCoreData3 (sortNumber 30)
MyCoreData4 (sortNumber 40)
```

and I will sort it by sortNumber "Desc"
But if I re-sort it, I have to build a complex (I guess it will be complex) logic to change the sortNumber of each element to the new sort order.

Have you any ideas how I can solve this?

**Code for Drag a row**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, acceptDrop info: NSDraggingInfo, row: Int, dropOperation: NSTableView.DropOperation) -> Bool {
        let pasteboard = info.draggingPasteboard()
        let pasteboardData = pasteboard.data(forType: NSPasteboard.PasteboardType.string)

        if let pasteboardData = pasteboardData {

            if let rowIndexes = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: pasteboardData) as? IndexSet {
                var oldIndexOffset = 0
                var newIndexOffset = 0

                for oldIndex in rowIndexes {

                    if oldIndex < row {
                        tableView.moveRow(at: oldIndex + oldIndexOffset, to: row - 1)
                        oldIndexOffset -= 1
                    } else {
                        tableView.moveRow(at: oldIndex, to: row + newIndexOffset)
                        newIndexOffset += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. This code **does** include the logic to update the UI (`tableView.moveRow...`). So you have to update the data source array and reindex the records as described.

Comment: I updated my first post with a new code. this code allows me to see the drag result directly without reload the tableview or fetch data again. but i don't know, how can I reindex my data object. is your code the correct one for this situation?

Comment: I'm using it myself in a few (Core Data) projects where a specific order is required.

Comment: on which position of my code should I include your code. I tried many "versions" but it doesn't work. I guess I do it wrong

Comment: Once again: You need to update the data source array (to get the same order as the table view). Are you using Cocoa Bindings? Then the data source array updates via KVC. In this case run the reindex code just at the end of the `acceptDrop` method before returning `true`.

Comment: I dont user cocoa bindings

Comment: Then you have to reorder the data source array in code. Consider to use Bindings. It makes things easier (less code, better performance)

Comment: yes and this is my problem. How should I reorder the data source array?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep a specific order you have to save the index as an attribute in Core Data.

The logic to re-index the records is not complicated. Whenever the order changes update the `index` attribute according to the position in the table view and save the context for example (assuming `items` is the data source array and the `NSManagedObject` subclass has a property `index`):

```
func reindex()
{
    for (index, item) in items.enumerated() { 
        item.index = Int32(index) 
    }
    saveContext()
}
```

When you fetch the data sort the records by `index`

Comment: maybe I think complicated as it is, But: my core data "Array" is a NSManagedObject. Each modification will directly save into core data. at the moment If I drag an element to another row, i save the new row number into core data, set the new row numbers of the other objects, fetch the data of core data again and reload my table View

Comment: You don't need to refetch the data and you don't need to reload the table view. You just need to change the index properties and save the context.

Comment: but If I don't reload the table view, how will the new order takes effect?

Comment: You wrote *I drag an element to another row* that implies you already changed the order in the UI (and also the data source array)

Comment: okay therefore is not code yet. at the moment i can do a drag action, but the row will not dragged in the UI. I can only check that this action will be done and do my logic from my first comment.

Comment: I use this code example for drag and drop (http://www.knowstack.com/swift-nstableview-drag-drop-in/) but every time the tableview will be reload after drag

Comment: The usual drag&drop logic is to handle the delegate methods (`acceptDrop`, `validateDrop` etc) and update the data source array.

Comment: yes but if you update the data source array, the tableview have to be reload to get the new order. think I wrong?

Comment: It's a **very bad** suggestion in the tutorial to reload the entire table view. It's much more efficient only to move the relevant rows with `insertRows` and `deleteRows`

Comment: Please watch the WWDC 2011(!) video about view based table views

Comment: this video is not very helpful because it will only shows objective-c. I need swift :(

Comment: But it describes the principle how to efficiently handle drag&drop. Rather than copy and paste code try to understand how things work. It's worth it.

Comment: I updated my first post with a new code. this code allows me to see the drag result directly without reload the tableview or fetch data again. but i don't know, how can I reindex my data object. is your code the correct one for this situation?